# For loop not using argument from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to run this function in my server.js file:

```
function formatArr (targetArr, characteristic, formattedArr) {
    console.log(characteristic);
    for (var i = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++) {
        formattedArr.push({characteristic:targetArr[i]})
    };
    return formattedArr;
};
```

If I call it like so:

```
var targetSize = Object.keys(JSON.parse(req.query.size)); //[s,m,l]
var sizeKey = "size";
// format size array for mongodb query 
var formattedSize = [];
var formattedSize = formatArr(targetSize, sizeKey, formattedSize);
console.log(formattedSize);
```

it DOES console log "size", but it does NOT replace the word characteristic with the word size in the formattedSize array.  Here's what I get in my server console:

```
size
[ { characteristic: 's' },{ characteristic: 'm' },{ characteristic: 'l' } ]
```

How do I make it replace characteristic with size within the array?  This is my desired output:

```
size
[ { size: 's' },{ size: 'm' },{ size: 'l' } ]
```

I want to be able to reuse the formatArr function with other characteristics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for variable property names:

```
function formatArr (targetArr, characteristic, formattedArr) {
    console.log(characteristic);
    for (var i = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[characteristic] = targetArr[i];
        formattedArr.push(obj);
    };
    return formattedArr;
};
```

A little verbose but still. If you are in ES2015 friendly environment you can use shorter syntax:

```
for (var i = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++) {
    formattedArr.push({[characteristic]: targetArr[i]});
};
```

Comment: We posted almost same answer at same time I would +1 you for great minds thinking alike but I am fresh out of votes today! =]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function formatArr (targetArr, characteristic, formattedArr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[characteristic:targetArr] = targetArr[i]
        formattedArr.push(obj)
    };
    return formattedArr;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In very new JavaScript environments, you can write:

```
    formattedArr.push({ [characteristic]: targetArr[i] })
```

Otherwise, you'll have to build an object step-by-step as in @dfsq's answer.

Comment: Thats cool. I didn't know that! Thanks. Learn something new everyday.